# Resize all images in all sub-directories of directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a directory that is structured as such:

```
├── directory 
|   ├── sub-directory_1
|   |   ├── img1.jpg               
|   |   └── img2.jpg 
|   |
|   ├── sub-directory_2
|   |   ├── img1.jpg               
|   |   └── img2.jpg 
.   .  
.   .  
.   .  
    .  
|   └── sub-directory_n              
|   |   ├── img1.jpg               
|   |   └── img2.jpg
```

I have this code that resizes all images in a directory:

```
from PIL import Image
import os, sys

path = "/directory"
dirs = os.listdir( path )

def resize():
    for item in dirs:
        if os.path.isfile(path+item):
            im = Image.open(path+item)
            f, e = os.path.splitext(path+item)
            imResize = im.resize((64,64), Image.ANTIALIAS)
            imResize.save(f + 'r.jpg', 'JPEG', quality=90)

resize()
```

Is there a way that I can modify it so that it iteratively resizes all the images in the sub directories?

Comment: Use [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) instead of [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir). You may also consider using [`pathlib.Path.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) to pick only the files with a given extension. In either case, be careful to generate all the names before hand to make sure you do not iterate over newly created files indefinitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this fit the bill

```
from PIL import Image
import os, sys

dir_path = "/directory"

def resize_im(path):
    if os.path.isfile(path):
        im = Image.open(path).resize((64,64), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        parent_dir = os.path.dirname(path)
        img_name = os.path.basename(path).split('.')[0]
        im.save(os.path.join(parent_dir, img_name + 'r.jpg'), 'JPEG', quality=90)

def resize_all(mydir):
    for subdir , _ , fileList in os.walk(mydir):
        for f in fileList:
            try:
                full_path = os.path.join(subdir,f)
                resize_im(full_path)
            except Exception as e:
                print('Unable to resize %s. Skipping.' % full_path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    resize_all(dir_path)
```

Be careful when you save the resized image inside the same directory of the source image. If you run your code twice, it will create lots of extra resized images.

Answer (score 0):

I have cobbled together answers from @Tu Bui and others on stack overflow to generate this, it also maintains aspect ration

```
from PIL import Image
import os, sys

dir_path = "/Users/tawanda/Downloads/images"

def resize_im(path):
    if os.path.isfile(path):
        parent_dir = os.path.dirname(path)
        img_name = os.path.basename(path).split('.')[0]
        img_extension = os.path.basename(path).split('.')[1]

        if img_extension.upper() not in ['PNG', 'JPG', 'JPEG']:
            print('invalid extension >>', img_extension)
            return


        img = Image.open(path);


        width, height = img.size;
        asp_rat = width/height;

        # Enter new width (in pixels)
        new_width = 900;

        # Enter new height (in pixels)
        new_height = 900;

        new_asp_rat = new_width/new_height;


        if (new_asp_rat == asp_rat):
            img = img.resize((new_width, new_height), Image.ANTIALIAS);

        # adjusts the height to match the width
        # NOTE: if you want to adjust the width to the height, instead ->
        # uncomment the second line (new_width) and comment the first one (new_height)
        else:
            new_height = round(new_width / asp_rat);
            #new_width = round(new_height * asp_rat);
            img = img.resize((new_width, new_height), Image.ANTIALIAS);


        if img_extension.upper() == 'PNG':
            print('png detected')
            img.save(os.path.join(parent_dir, img_name + '_resized.png'), 'PNG', quality=90)
        else:
            img.save(os.path.join(parent_dir, img_name + '_resized.jpg'), 'JPEG', quality=90)
        print(f'resized {img_name}.{img_extension}')
        os.remove(path)

def resize_all(mydir):
    for subdir , _ , fileList in os.walk(mydir):
        for f in fileList:
            try:
                full_path = os.path.join(subdir,f)
                resize_im(full_path)
            except Exception as e:
                print('Unable to resize %s. Skipping.' % full_path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    resize_all(dir_path)
```