# Resize all images in all sub-directories of directory file size more than 10MB

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, resize, image-resizing

I am designing a python script resize all directory and sub directory of image file [ .png, .jpeg, .jpg] which size larger than 10 MB. I have reference to this following link [Resize all images in all sub-directories of directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56346358/resize-all-images-in-all-sub-directories-of-directory) for design.

However, I have resulting "Unable to resize C:\intersteller\StaticFileBasePath\3.jpg. Skipping." while run in jupyter notebook.

May I seek your help for identify the root casue in my script?

```py
from PIL import Image
import os, sys
import PIL
import glob

dir_path = r'C:\intersteller\StaticFileBasePath'


def resize_im(path):
    for foldername, subfolders, photos in os.walk(dir_path):
        for filename in photos:
            if filename.endswith(('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png')) and os.path.getsize(os.path.join(foldername, filename))>10000000:
                        print(foldername + '\\' + filename)
                
                        parent_dir = os.path.dirname(dir_path)
                        img_name = os.path.basename(dir_path).split('.')[0]
                        img_extension = os.path.basename(dir_path).split('.')[1]
                
                        if img_extension.upper() not in ['PNG', 'JPG', 'JPEG']:
                            print('invalid extension >>', img_extension)
                            return
                
                        img = Image.open(dir_path);
                
                        width, height = img.size;
                        asp_rat = width/height;
                
                        # Enter new width (in pixels)
                        new_width = 2775;
                
                        # Enter new height (in pixels)
                        new_height = 3700;
                
                        new_asp_rat = new_width/new_height;
                
                        if (new_asp_rat == asp_rat):
                            img = img.resize((new_width, new_height), Image.ANTIALIAS);
                    
                            # adjusts the height to match the width
                            # NOTE: if you want to adjust the width to the height, instead ->
                            # uncomment the second line (new_width) and comment the first one (new_height)
                        else:
                            new_height = round(new_width / asp_rat);
                            #new_width = round(new_height * asp_rat);
                            img = img.resize((new_width, new_height), Image.ANTIALIAS);
                        
                        if img_extension.upper() == 'PNG':
                            print('png deteced')
                            img.save(os.path.join(parent_dirm + 'new', img_name + 'resized.png'), 'PNG', quality=50)
                        else:
                            img.save(os.path.join(parent_dirm + 'new', img_name + 'resized.jpeg'), 'JPEG', quality=50)

def resize_all(mydir):
    for foldername, subfolders, photos in os.walk(dir_path):
        for filename in photos:
            if filename.endswith(('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png')) and os.path.getsize(os.path.join(foldername, filename))>10000000:
                try:
                    full_path = os.path.join(foldername, filename)
                    resize_im(full_path)
                except Exception as e:
                    print('Unable to resize %s. Skipping.' % full_path)                    

                
if __name__ == '__main__':
    resize_all(dir_path)
```

Result:
C:\intersteller\StaticFileBasePath\3.jpg
Unable to resize C:\intersteller\StaticFileBasePath\3.jpg. Skipping.
C:\intersteller\StaticFileBasePath\3.jpg
Unable to resize C:\intersteller\StaticFileBasePath\4.jpg. Skipping.

Many Thanks

Get resize of dir_path

Answer (score 0):

To find the root cause of your issue in this code, you may want to print the exception that occurs in your `resize_all` function.

Add the following snippet to your code:

```py
except Exception as e:
    print('Unable to resize %s. Skipping.' % full_path) 
    print('Got error:', e)
```

This will allow you to see what exactly the error is. This additional information may help you resolve your problem.

Comment: Hi, The error is 'Got error: list index out of range'; Does it means the list of the index in (jpeg', 'jpg', 'png)?

Comment: Without the full error, it's difficult to tell, but I would guess the issue is in this line `img_extension = os.path.basename(dir_path).split('.')[1]`. Could you edit your question to include the full error message?

Comment: Hi, I can run the code after verify now. 
Many Thanks

Comment: but I found other problem that some of photos were rotated  after compressed

Comment: @kensonkf I belive in that case the best course of action you have is to open another question